# How to code add to linked list so you can print from the oldest to newest item?

Tags: c#, linked-list, console.writeline

Okay so I have to print out a linked list from the order I put it in. Each node refers to a ticket object, and the ticket object has its own print function that I can call upon. I can remove the start of the list and refer it to the next ticket, but have it coded so that it prints out the newest to oldest. I believe the problem lies in my code that allows me to add a ticket to the list:

```
    private class TicketNode 
    { //basic node
        public TicketNode next;
        public Ticket data;

        public TicketNode(Ticket tic)
        {
            data = tic;
        }
    }
    public void PrintAll()
    {//Prints all tickets
        TicketNode cur = first;
        while (cur != null)
        {
            cur.data.PrintDescription();
            cur = cur.next;
        }
    }
    public void AddTicket(Ticket t)
    {
        TicketNode ticNode; //creates a new node

        if (first == null) //for kick-starting the list
            first = new TicketNode(t);
        else
        {
            ticNode = new TicketNode(t); //initializes node
            ticNode.next = first; 
            first = ticNode; //first.next is the ticket that was ticNode
        } 
    }
```

ex: I put in the tickets with strings "Low", "Another Low", and "Final Low" and when I want to print it out I expect:

Low
Another Low
Final Low

Instead I get:
Final Low
Another Low
Low

If I were to remove to oldest ("Low") I should see something like this next time  print:
Another Low
Final Low

Any ideas on a how to reorient the list?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to insert new items at the end of the list. To do that in O(1), you need to keep a pointer `last` to the last item in the list. When you insert a new item, you use that pointer to quickly get the last item, append the new item and update the pointer.

With that modification, you can iterate from `first` via `next` and actually get the items in their insert order.

Answer (score 0):

While Adding element into linked list, you have find end of the list and there. Following code might be useful for you 
AddTicket method is sholud be like this

```
void AddTicket(Ticket t)
{
    TicketNode ticNode; //creates a new node

    if (first == null) //for kick-starting the list
        first = new TicketNode(t);
    else
    {
        ticNodeNew = new TicketNode(t);
        TicketNode ticNode; = first;
        while(ticNode.next != null)
        {
            ticNode = ticNode.next;
        }

        ticNode.next = ticNodeNew;
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your linked list, the an item references the next oldest, etc. The most recent is first in the list, and the oldest items is at the end of the list. That is why when you run through the list in `PrintAll()` you get items youngest to oldest.

You need to print your list out in reverse order and an easy way of doing that is to use a Stack.

```
  public void PrintAll()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<TicketNode>();
        TicketNode cur = first;
        while (cur != null)
        {
            stack.Push(cur);
            cur = cur.next;
        }

        while (stack.Count > 0)
            stack.Pop().data.PrintDescription();
    }
```

MH09's solution which stores the list in oldest to youngest order is also valid. MH09's solution traverses the entire list on AddTicket(), my solution traverses the list in PrintAll(). You might want to choose which solution is better suited to you on the basis of performance. However in both cases the traversal is O(n).